# Simplicial nerve of a simplicial natural transformation

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

In Higher Topos Theory, Lurie describes the simplicial nerve functor taking as input
a simplicially enriched category $\mathcal C$ and outputting the ∞-category
$\mathrm{N}(\mathcal C)$.

The construction is functorial in the following way: if $F \colon \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$
is a simplicially enriched functor between two simplicially enriched categories,
then $\mathrm{N}(F)$ is a functor from $\mathrm{N}(\mathcal C)$ to $\mathrm{N}(\mathcal D)$.
This defines a functor from the 1-category of simplicially enriched categories and simplically
enriched functors to the category of simplicial sets.

`What happens to the simplicial natural transformations?`

I believe that on several occasions the following is used: simplicial natural
isomorphisms are sent to invertible natural transformations.
Is there a quick way to see this or a reference for it?

Comment: The nerve functor preserves products, so after converting your simplicial natural transformation to a functor $\mathcal{C} \times [1] \to \mathcal{D}$, take the nerve to obtain a functor $N (\mathcal{C}) \times N ([1]) \to N (\mathcal{D})$, which corresponds to a natural transformation between functors $N (\mathcal{C}) \to N (\mathcal{D})$, because $N ([1]) \cong \Delta^1$. A similar version of this argument can be used to see that simplicial natural isomorphisms correspond to natural isomorphisms.

Comment: That is indeed a perfect and quick way to see this :-)